# Slicing account balance data in BigQuery to generate a debit report

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a collection of account balances over time:

```
+-----------------+------------+-------------+-----------------------+
| account_balance | department | customer_id |  timestamp            |
+-----------------+------------+-------------+-----------------------+
| 5               | A          | 1           |  2019-02-12T00:00:00  |
| -10             | A          | 1           |  2019-02-13T00:00:00  |
| -35             | A          | 1           |  2019-02-14T00:00:00  |
| 20              | A          | 1           |  2019-02-15T00:00:00  |
+-----------------+------------+-------------+-----------------------+
```

Each record shows the total account balance of a customer at a specified timestamp. The account balance increases e.g. to 20 from -35, when a customer tops-up his account with 55. As a customer uses a services, his account balances decreases e.g. from 5 to -10.

I want to aggregate this data in two ways:

1) Get the debit, credit and balance (credit-debit) of a department per month and year. The results from April should be a summary of all previous months:

```
+---------+--------+-------+------------+-------+--------+
| balance | credit | debit | department | month |  year  |
+---------+--------+-------+------------+-------+--------+
| 5       | 10     | -5    | A          | 1     |  2019  |
| 20      | 32     | -12   | A          | 2     |  2019  |
| 35      | 52     | -17   | A          | 3     |  2019  |
| 51      | 70     | -19   | A          | 4     |  2019  |
+---------+--------+-------+------------+-------+--------+
```

A customer's account balance might not change every month. There might be account balance records of customer 1 in February, but not March.

Notes towards the solution:

- use `EXTRACT(MONTH from timestamp) month`
- use `EXTRACT(YEAR from timestamp) year`
- `GROUP BY month, year, department`

2) Get the change of debit, credit and balance of a department by date.

```
+---------+--------+-------+------------+-------------+
| balance | credit | debit | department |  date       |
+---------+--------+-------+------------+-------------+
| 5       | 10     | -5    | A          | 2019-01-15  |
| 15      | 22     | -7    | A          | 2019-02-15  |
| 15      | 20     | -5    | A          | 2019-03-15  |
| 16      | 18     | -2    | A          | 2019-04-15  |
+---------+--------+-------+------------+-------------+
  51       70       -19
```

When I create a SUM of the deltas, I should get the same values as the last row from results in 1).

Notes towards the solution:

- use `account_balance - LAG(account_balance) OVER(PARTITION BY department ORDER BY timestamp ASC) delta` to compute deltas

Comment: I would recommend you to revisit your question and make it more focused and specific with good data example and expected result. otherwise it is small chance that someone will be able to answer it as it is now

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant thanks for the feedback! I revised my question.

Comment: to be honest - your `notes toward the solution` looks irrelevant here! you would rather provide more details on logic you have in mind. for example how those numbers are to be calculated for both outputs. you can say it is obvious - and maybe it is  - but from my experience on SO i know that there is always something that then happens to be not how OP meant it to be - so, for me for example  - I don't want to spend my time to try to come up with something that would reverse engineer your logic and then realize it is not what you meant - I think the rest of us here on SO feel the same way ...

Comment: ... and that is why you don't really see any reasonable answers as of yet. Just my thoughts

Answer (score 2):

Your question is unclear, but it sounds like you want to get the outstanding balance at any given point in time.

The following query does this for 1 point in time.

```
with calendar as (
  select cast('2019-06-01' as timestamp) as balance_calc_ts
),
most_recent_balance as (
  select customer_id, balance_calc_ts,max(timestamp) as most_recent_balance_ts
  from <table>
  cross join calendar
  where timestamp < balance_calc_ts -- or <=
  group by 1,2
)
select t.customer_id, t.account_balance, mrb.balance_calc_ts
from <table> t
inner join most_recent_balance mrb on t.customer_id = mrb.customer_id and t.timestamp = mrb.balance_calc_ts
```

If you need to calculate it at a series of points in time, you will need to modify the calendar CTE to return more dates.  This is the beauty of CROSS JOINS in BQ!

Comment: mrb is not defined. balance_calc_ts cannot be reached within most_recent_balance (SELECT list expression references column balance_calc_ts which is neither grouped nor aggregated)

Comment: editing post, the most_recent_balance CTE needs to change `group by 1` to `group by 2`